# Add source model to attribute in magento

Tags: php, magento

I created an install script to add two fields to customer using the script below.

But I get this error.

```
Source model "" not found for attribute "dob_month"
```

Am I not defining the model in the first line? What does that actually do? What is the best way to fix this?

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');


$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'dob_month', array(
    'label'     => 'Month',
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'input'     => 'dropdown',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => true,
    'position'  => 1,
    'option'    => array (
        'value' => array (
            'optionone'    => array('January'),
            'optiontwo'    => array('February'),
            'optionthree'  => array('March'),
            'optionfour'   => array('April'),
            'optionfive'   => array('May'),
            'optionsix'    => array('June'),
            'optionseven'  => array('July'),
            'optioneight'  => array('August'),
            'optionnine'   => array('September'),
            'optionten'    => array('October'),
            'optioneleven' => array('November'),
            'optiontwelve' => array('December')
        )
    )
));

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'dob_year', array (
    'label'     => 'Year',
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => true,
    'position'  => 1
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source model is used when Magento needs to know possible values of your attribute. For example, when rendering dropdown for your attribute. So no, you're not defining it. If my memory doesn't fail me, you can do that by adding 'source' to attribute definition array. Something like:

```
...
'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table'
...
```

That will mean that all your possible options are stored in tables eav_attribute_option and eav_attribute_option. So if your options from install script are successfully added to these tables, that should work. Or you can write your own source model, which I prefer more.

Answer (score 5):

If you've already added the attribute, you'll want to use `updateAttribute` to set the source model value in the `eav_attribute` table.

```
<?php

$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/setup','default_setup');
/***
 * When working with EAV entities it's important to use their module's setup class.
 * See Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup::_prepareValues() to understand why.
 */

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->updateAttribute(
    'customer',
    'dob_month',
    'source_model', //a.o.t. 'source'
    'whatever/source_model',
)

$installer->endSetup();
```

If not, then you can use `addAttribute()`, which - due to the `Mage_Eav` setup class' `_prepareValues()` method - requires an alias for the source_model column as indicated in Alexei's answer ('source' as opposed to 'source_model').